# Don't Rearrange Gnome Desktop Icons in Dual Monitor Setup

Tags: gnome, multi-monitor, icons

Everytime I connect or disconnect my laptop from my second monitor (on the left) my icons get scrambled. I would like my icons to always stay on my laptop screen in the order I set them.

I think the solution should look something like

`gsetting set org.gnome.shell.desktop rearrange.desktop-icons false`

Comment: I have exact same problem on my Ubuntu 18.04. I have seen many similar issues on Stackoverflow and Superuser so it must be a bug. What OS are you running?